# Outlook UI Hangs - Still running in Task Manager

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, freeze, task-manager

Title: Outlook UI hanging without 'not responding' alert, process still running in Task Manager

Body:
I have an end user experiencing a perplexing issue with Outlook 365. Despite the UI hanging, Outlook doesn’t display any ‘not responding’ alerts. The process continues to run in Task Manager, rendering the application unresponsive until manually terminated and reopened.

The end user's Outlook is equipped with essential add-ins such as Zoom, iManage Work 10, Adobe, etc. Attempts to resolve the issue have included recreating the profile & OST, running quick and online repairs, reinstalling the application, and resetting the view. Unfortunately, none of these measures have proven successful.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue in their environment? If so, I’m open to any suggestions or solutions to troubleshoot and resolve this issue effectively. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the user have multiple accounts? Have you checked for low system resources on the user's computer? Have the PST/OST files grown too big? Have you tried to disable some of the add-ons (you could use Outlook in Safe mode if the user can work without all of them for some time)?